# Ninject binding based on object's property? Convention or contextual binding?

Tags: c#, binding, ninject, ninject-extensions, contextual-binding

I have an interface:

```
public interface IInterface
{
string Get(obj o);
}
```

and I have the 2 classes:

```
public class C1 : IInterface
{
string Get(obj o);
}

public class C2 : IInterface
{
string Get(obj o);
}
```

I'd like to send in o and then have Ninject determine which interface it is based on the property of o. Obj being something like:

```
public class obj
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like something that's like:

```
Bind<IInterface>().To<C1>.When(obj.Name == "C1");
Bind<IInterface>().To<C2>.When(obj.Name == "C2");
```

but I haven't worked with Ninject before. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've messed up your example. How could you ever instanciate an `IInterface` if doing so requires accessing an instance of `IInterface`? You couldn't. Do you mean to pass in the `obj` with a `Name` property to a factory which then returns `IInterface`?

Comment: could you please "fix" the question so that the Q/A will be valuable to later readers, too? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been somewhat liberal with the interpretation of your question, because i think you've skipped some "thinking steps" and necessary information.

However, what I recommend is doing it like this:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IFactory
{
    IInterface Create(INamed obj);
}

public class Factory : IFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public Factory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IInterface Create(INamed obj) 
    {
        return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IInterface>(obj.Name);
    }
}
```

**Alternative**: you could also use the [ninject factory extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory). Sadly enough it does not support named bindings by default, but you can customize it do so like documented [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface:-Referencing-Named-Bindings#example-customisation-treating-the-first-factory-method-parameter-as-a-name-specifier).

However to be perfectly frank i would rather go for manually implementing the factory, because it is more easily understandable. If i would be customizing the factory - which i have done - i would consider adding support for attributes (which specify how to handle a factory method parameter) instead of having to configure each `.ToFactory()` binding how it will interpret parameters.

Comment: Thanks! A friend of mine suggested the factory pattern as well.
Could you clarify the IResolutionRoot portion of it?

Comment: ninject's kernel is implementing the `IKernel` interface which in turn is deriving from `IBindingRoot` and `IResolutionRoot`. `IBindingRoot` is used for creating bindings (`Bind().To()...`) and `IResolutionRoot` is used for retrieving/instantiating types. You do not need to `Bind<IResolutionRoot>`, it's already bound by ninject. The ninject factory extension for example is internally also using the `IResolutionRoot` to instantiate types.